# getStaticProps returns null

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have two db queries in my getStaticProps, both return the values correctly, but when I return the props, only one of them returns correct data, the other will become null. What's wrong?

```
const Dash = (props) => {

const config = props.config;

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("config", props.config) /* returns null*/
}, []);

return(/*...*/)
}

export const getStaticProps = async (ctx) => {
  const dbConnection: mysql.Connection = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    socketPath: process.env.DB_SOCKET
})

  const newsRes = dbConnection.query(`SELECT * FROM ucp_news`)
  const configRes = dbConnection.query(`SELECT * FROM ucp_config`)

  const responses = await Promise.all([newsRes, configRes])

  console.log(responses[1][0][0]) /* returns config value correctly */

  dbConnection.destroy()
  return {
    props: {
      news: responses[0][0], /* returns correct value */
      config: responses[1][0][0]  /* returns null instead of config value */
    }
  }

}

export default Dash;
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind stringifying it, and then parsing it back? Is it to create a copy? Also, what does stringify function return?

Comment: It returns the correct data which I need.

Comment: responses[1][0][0] has the data you need, calling stringify, and then parse on it again will just give you the same data that responses[1][0][0] already has. The only difference is that now you should have a new copy of the data. Why are you not just doing `return { props: { news: responses[0][0], config: responses[1][0][0] } };`? There seems to be no reason for you to need to stringify it and then parse it back other than getting a deep copy, which I assume you do not need in this case.

Comment: Also, node mysql is not promise-friendly out of the box. You are either using dbConnection.query wrong, or you have some extra code that we haven't seen that promisifies it. Are you using promise-mysql?

Comment: The queries are working and they return the correct data. I changed the code you suggested, but the problem still remains. I still get null as the prop value for some reason.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the serialization of the object to json. What are you using to wrap the mysql functions into promises? Because, by default, the mysql package cannot be used in the way you are using it. It uses callbacks instead of promises. I want to get an idea of what kind of result you are getting so I can understand how to properly serialize it.

Comment: I am using the mysql2 package which has promises https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper

Comment: But when I `console.log(responses[1][0][0])` it returns the data so that should not be the problem.

Comment: Can you edit the post and show how you are consuming the `config` prop in your React component? This code seems fine, there has to be something else wrong.

Comment: I updated the question with the necessary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been passing a config named prop from _app and that has been overwriting the prop passed from getStaticProps.

Comment: I figured it was something outside of the code you posted because I have tested it locally and it worked. Could not replicate your issue in any way. You can mark your answer as the accepted one.